# How to select only the records with the highest date in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table, 'lasttraces', with the following fields.

```
Id, AccountId, Version, DownloadNo, Date
```

The data looks like this:

```
28092|15240000|1.0.7.1782|2009040004731|2009-01-20 13:10:22.000
28094|61615000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007696|2009-01-20 13:11:38.000
28095|95317000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007695|2009-01-20 13:10:18.000
28101|15240000|1.0.7.1782|2009040004740|2009-01-20 14:10:22.000
28103|61615000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007690|2009-01-20 14:11:38.000
28104|95317000|1.0.7.1782|2009040007710|2009-01-20 14:10:18.000
```

How can I, in [LINQ to SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query#LINQ_to_SQL), only get the last lasttrace of every AccountId (the one with the highest date)?

Comment: actually in your example all logs with the same account id, have the exact same date, so which one takes preference in that case?

Answer (score 252, accepted):

If you just want the last date for each account, you'd use this:

```
var q = from n in table
        group n by n.AccountId into g
        select new {AccountId = g.Key, Date = g.Max(t=>t.Date)};
```

If you want the whole record:

```
var q = from n in table
        group n by n.AccountId into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(t=>t.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Oracle doesn't support this. If query performance is out of your consideration, you can convert table ToList before you do the query.

Comment: It would be great if you can post a `method-chain` solution for this.

Comment: second query - shouldn't it be `(from n in table ...).First()`?

Comment: @JasonL, no.  The `First()` call should apply to the `g.Order...` expression (subquery).

Comment: @Mehrdad Afshari  **thats amazing**, I wanted the second one primarily but they are both now in my snippets as **so very useful**.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!!

Comment: OrderByDescending(t => t.Date)' could not be translated. (the weak EF)

Answer (score 57):

Here is a simple way to do it

```
var lastPlayerControlCommand = this.ObjectContext.PlayerControlCommands
                                .Where(c => c.PlayerID == player.ID)
                                .OrderByDescending(t=>t.CreationTime)
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

Also have a look this great LINQ place - [LINQ to SQL Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688085)

Comment: This solution works fine if you were querying per account but does not do what OP stated, which is to get the most recent result for all records without providing an AccountId (in your case PlayerId)

Comment: This solution inspired me to order instead to try to select the maximum. +1

Comment: This solution may lead to "Sequence contains no elements" Error in Linq right?

Answer (score 54):

If you want the whole record,here is a lambda way:

```
var q = _context
             .lasttraces
             .GroupBy(s => s.AccountId)
             .Select(s => s.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Worked Great.  Thanks.

Comment: This is the key here.

Answer (score 6):

It could be something like:

```
var qry = from t in db.Lasttraces
          group t by t.AccountId into g
          orderby t.Date
          select new { g.AccountId, Date = g.Max(e => e.Date) };
```

Answer (score 3):

Go a simple way to do this :-

Created one class to hold following information

- Level (number)
- Url (Url of the site)

Go the list of sites stored on a ArrayList object.  And executed following query to sort it in descending order by Level.

```
var query = from MyClass object in objCollection 
    orderby object.Level descending 
    select object
```

Once I got the collection sorted in descending order,  I wrote following code to get the Object that comes as top row

```
MyClass topObject = query.FirstRow<MyClass>()
```

This worked like charm.

Comment: This gave me a better idea than my original thought. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

LINQ's `.OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault()` approach is good. But the https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ people do it better: `.MaxBy()`

Example:

```
IEnumerable<Person> data = Data.GetPersons();
Person oldestPerson = data.MaxBy(p => p.Age);
```

Or in the latest version of MoreLINQ, they have changed the return type:

```
IEnumerable<Person> data = Data.GetPersons();
IEnumerable<Person> oldestPersons = data.MaxBy(p => p.Age);
Person oldestPerson = oldestPersons.First();
```

So what used to be `.MaxBy()` is now `.MaxBy().First()`. This has the advantage that you can handle more than 1 result (used to be only the first person with the max age, but there may be more persons with the same age). Another advantage is that `.MaxBy()` can now handle an empty `IEnumerable<T>` without throwing an exception. Of course, the exception occurs in `.First()` then, but you can decide to use `.FirstOrDefault()` instead to avoid this.