# LINQ VB how to select records with the max date (highest date)

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

I know how to do this in C#, but my dev team doesn't use C#...

here is the answer in C#:
[How to select only the records with the highest date in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470440/linq-how-to-select-only-the-records-with-the-highest-date)

How do I do this in VB?

Essentially, if I knew how to write lambda expressions in VB, I would be set, but the materials I have found are not helpful.

I also need to know why the `Into` identifier (i.e. "`g`") is always trying to be a function every time I move off the line, resulting in this error:

http://img19.imageshack.us/i/errno.png/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's an example [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386922.aspx) of grouping in VB:

```
Dim query = From p In db.Products _
            Group p By p.CategoryID Into g = Group _
            Select CategoryID, MaxPrice = g.Max(Function(p) p.UnitPrice)
```

If you omit the "= Group", it will consider g as a function.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 8):

```
Dim q = From n In table _
        Group n By n.AccountId Into g _
        Select g.OrderByDescending(Function(t) t.Date).First()
```

Comment: as I put that into my code, the pre-compiler (I  think) keeps turning "g" into "g()" as soon as I move off the line, thus throwing an error. It thinks g needs be a function ??

Comment: this code does not work. "g" is not an acceptable "groupname"

Comment: @Joel: There's still a problem with the group Into g which doesn't work in VB.

Comment: That actually just confuses the compiler. "Group" is a key word. The environment keeps trying to add "()" after "g", like it is supposed to be a function. I am wondering if that is because this code is in an event handler in a class (don't know why that would make a difference), or if it is because I might have an outdated version of the framework? All I know is that it doesn't work as is.

Comment: Did you try it with Group? You could also try "Group n By n.AccountId Into g = Group"...