# max date in a group by LINQ and VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a table with Settlement_date, Settlement_period , Publishing_date, Zone_Indicator and Demand_outturn.

The data is added to the table with  a new demand_outturn estimate several times per date for the same settlement_Date, Settlement_period and Zone_indicator with a new publishing_date

I have managed to produce the code below in VB.net that lists the max publishing_date data for each period and outputs to LINQpad. However, i'm struggling to put this to a graph in ASP.net using

For each MWT in query5

next

where I can't find the data elements

```
 dim query5 = from Q in sys_indDEMs
where q.settlement_date = "2016-03-20" _
and Q.zone_indicator = "N"
group Q by Q.settlement_period into g = group _
Select perioddata = g, _
MW = From p2 In g Where p2.publishing_date = g.Max(Function(p3)         p3.publishing_date)
```

Comment: `where q.settlement_date = "2016-03-20"` what is `settlement_date`?  If it is an actual DateTime type you are comparing to string and Option Strict is off

Comment: all the dates are date time

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470440/how-to-select-only-the-records-with-the-highest-date-in-linq

Comment: Nearly all text is about a query you seem to have working without any problem and suddenly, almost casually, you say *i'm struggling to put this to a graph*. **What *exactly* is your question?**